# Hyperlink to named cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!"&CELL("address";$A5);"Link")
```

works great. How can I link to a named cell?

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!"&CELL("address";cellname);"Link")
```

does not work....

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!"&CELL("address", hello), "Link")` works for me (using `,` instead of `;`). The named cell is called `hello`. [HYPERLINK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/hyperlink-HP005209116.aspx) and [CELL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx)

Comment: Just found this. You could see if this is the problem? [`,` or `;`](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/385317-semicolon-comma-regional.html)

Comment: That indeed solved the problem. However, this raises the problem of missing type hinting which is really painful if you have a lot of named cells...
I've tried a simpler variant instead:
`=HYPERLINK(cellname;"Link")`
This leads to an error: Cannot open the specified file.
Any ideas how I can preserve the type hinting?

Comment: That simplified version should work if you use a comma instead of a semicolon. I'll look into the type hinting problem when I get back to my computer. I'm out right now on my phone. I'll also add the solution I said as an answer when I get back

Comment: No difference... comma or semicolon just depends on the Excel setting for decimal operators.

Comment: OK, back at my computer. Sorry for the stupid question, but what do you mean by type hinting? I don't think I understand you. If you have a lot of named cells, you can just select the cell when typing formulas just like you would with a normal cell...

Comment: Sorry, I mean auto-completion. Excel will display a list of possible values of named ranges when you start typing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address", NamedCellName), "Friendly link name")` and it worked.